# iOS TBD file instead of a Mach-O binary

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, iokit

### Environment

- Jail Broken iOS 8.4
- Xcode 7
- OS-X 10.10

### Problem at hand

I am trying to find the IOKit ARM7 binary file but all I can find is 'IOKit.tbd', ‘IOKit.tbd’ is a text only file of the following form:

```
---
archs:           [ armv7, armv7s, arm64 ]
platform:        ios
install-name:    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
current-version: 275.0
exports:         
  - archs:           [ armv7, armv7s ]
    symbols:      [ _IOConnectMethodScalarIScalarO, _IOConnectMethodScalarIStructureI,
…
```

The IOKit binary file is neither found on the Jail Broken device on the following path:

```
“/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/”
```

**OR**, on the Xcode.app Package at

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A
```

On the latter I get 'IOKit.tbd', Searching the iOS fileSys for IOKit result the following:

```
iPod-touch:/ root# find . iname 'IOKit*' -type f | grep IOKit
./System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/Info.plist
./System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
```

On the OS-X FileSys the binary *IS found* under the following path:

```
 /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
```

However, it includes code only for the X86 and the X86_64 instruction sets and not to the ARM instruction set

---

### Where is the ARM IOKit binary located?
 How can I get direct access to the IOKit file?

Answer (score 1):

- On the MacOS there are only the x86 & x64 binaries, these are used w/ the simulators that execute the x86/x64 flavor of MacO binary, these R located under /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks
- The ARM equivalent libs are found on physical devices under the same folder ( /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks ), use a Jail Broken device to get these.
- Additional ARM private frameworks can be found on the developer image mounted by xcode when launching an app on the device, these are found under '%DMG Root%/DeveloperDiskImage/Library/PrivateFrameworks/'.

Answer (score -1):

For iOS development, you need to get it from here:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework